# Run JavaScript code directly from a local file on any existing page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, monkeypatching

You can open a browser's Dev-Tools on any page and write & run JavaScript-Code in the console.

However I now need to run ("inject" into an existing page) JavaScript code that is about ~5 million characters in length. The browser really can't handle if I copy-paste that into the console, like I'd do with smaller code snippets - it freezes for 30+ minutes.

I think the only reason it struggles is because it's trying to display all of that code.

Therefore, if I could just load the code directly from a local file, without it being displayed in the console, it should work flawlessly.

How can I do that?

*(On any browser, but Firefox primarily)*

Comment: you can place this code on a web accessible place like a web server, and load it using `<script>` tag

Comment: does `<script src='file://....'>` work?

Comment: @ChrisCodesThings: No, that doesn’t work.

Comment: I use tampermonkey on Chrome. Just checked and it's available on Firefox as well: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/

Comment: @miken32: That won’t help run code *on an existing webpage* (think Tampermonkey – which has already been mentioned).

Comment: @slebetman Oh I didn't know It can access local files! I'll try it out, thank you.

Comment: @Ry- Maybe with "Node" he was refering to goldman's idea "place this code on a web accessible place like a web server"... Or you're right and he just didn't understand the question, would explain where that dislike is from .. :D

Comment: @FireFuro99 you’re right, I missed the part where they mentioned injecting into a web page. I agree Tampermionkey is the right choice.

Comment: In addition to a userscript manager extension: Chrome has support for [JS snippets](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets), and there has been some [discussion](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/why-dont-you-provide-functionality-for-saving-code-snippets-in-firefox/72792) about this for Firefox as well.